# MATPLOTLIB - bar headings for multiple bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I'm new with python/matplotlib and I need some help adding bar headings to all my bars. Currently, this code creates a bar graph with a heading on only one bar in each series, I'm not sure what's going on and I greatly appreciate any help. The data is irrelevant, just trying to get the code ready.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use(['science', 'no-latex'])

system_x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
x_indexes = np.arange(len(system_x))
width = 0.2

cof_diamond = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2]
for i, v in enumerate(cof_diamond):
    plt.text(x_indexes[i] - 0.35, v + 0.05, str(v), color='black')
plt.bar(x_indexes - width, cof_diamond, label='diamond', color='crimson', width=width)

cof_3000 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2]
for i, v in enumerate(cof_3000):
    plt.text(x_indexes[i] - 0.35, v + 0.05, str(v), color='black')
plt.bar(x_indexes, cof_3000, label='$ta-C_{3000K}$', color='slategrey', width=width)

cof_4000 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2]
for i, v in enumerate(cof_4000):
    plt.text(x_indexes[i] - 0.35, v + 0.05, str(v), color='black')
plt.bar(x_indexes + width, cof_4000, label='$ta-C_{4000K}$', color='orange', width=width)

plt.xticks(ticks=x_indexes, labels=system_x)

plt.xlabel('System Type')
plt.ylabel('CoF')
plt.title('Mean CoF')

leg = plt.legend()

leg_lines = leg.get_lines()
leg_texts = leg.get_texts()

plt.setp(leg_lines, linewidth=4)

plt.grid(False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three of your `plt.text` calls have the same X coordinates.

Change them to

```
plt.text(x_indexes[i] - 0.35, v + 0.05, str(v), color='black')
...
plt.text(x_indexes[i], v + 0.05, str(v), color='black')
...
plt.text(x_indexes[i] + 0.35, v + 0.05, str(v), color='black')
```

will fix it. You can change 0.35 to a more appropriate number to make it look prettier.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the method [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#grouped-bar-chart-with-labels):

[image]

```
system_x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
x_indexes = np.arange(len(system_x))
width = 0.2


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cof_diamond = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2]
r0 = ax.bar(x_indexes - width, cof_diamond, label='diamond', color='crimson', width=width)

cof_3000 = [2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2]
r1 = ax.bar(x_indexes, cof_3000, label='$ta-C_{3000K}$', color='slategrey', width=width)

cof_4000 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2]
r2 = ax.bar(x_indexes + width, cof_4000, label='$ta-C_{4000K}$', color='orange', width=width)


def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')
autolabel(r0)
autolabel(r1)
autolabel(r2)

plt.xticks(ticks=x_indexes, labels=system_x)

plt.xlabel('System Type')
plt.ylabel('CoF')
plt.title('Mean CoF')

leg = plt.legend()

leg_lines = leg.get_lines()
leg_texts = leg.get_texts()

plt.setp(leg_lines, linewidth=4)

plt.grid(False)

plt.tight_layout()
```

The exellent example you posted made this very easy to answer.  Thanks! For the future, both for posting here and debugging on your own, if you make the example with unusual and non-identical numbers you will generally find your errors more quickly.  Here's your example, but with different numbers:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the advice, so the values were just plotting on themselves - silly error

Comment: @Jhelum12121: yes, but I think the two broader things are (and why I posted a soln): 1) using the autolabel function here is helpful; 2) use weirder data when testing. ie, it's not the there was a small mistake, but that you want to have methods where such mistakes are less likely.